# PayPal IPN callbacks only allowed on a https domains?

Tags: php, paypal, listener, paypal-ipn

I am trying to make my first IPN listener to connect my site with PayPal for different actions on IPN's.

I see in the documents "PayPal no longer supports HTTP for post backs" ([more details](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1916&viewlocale=en_US)). Does it mean my site (with the ipn listener script have to be on https domain or does only mean i have to send my verify callback to paypal's "https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" adress and not to "https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the document, you should call the PayPal end points only with https. (Otherwise your request will be denied)
Your site don't need an SSL certificate.

Comment: Great. Thanks for clarifying that!